# How can I put a custom property into my pie menu?

Tags: python, scripting, properties, pie-menu

I'm playing around with pie menus in blender. I used the default pie menu template and customized it to suit. But now I have four custom properties on a model and I want to edit them with the pie menu. I followed along one of Sebastians Konig's tutorials but he only used very basic tools like smooth shading etc. He simply right clicked > edit source, but doing that on my custom shaders takes me to this:

```
row.prop(rna_item, '["%s"]' % escape_identifier(key), text="")
```

And doing that to any of my custom properties leads me to the same place. How can I access the custom properties and put them into my pie menu?

Here is my code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu

# spawn an edit mode selection pie (run while object is in edit mode to get a valid output)


class VIEW3D_PIE_template(Menu):
    # label is displayed at the center of the pie menu.
    bl_label = "Macbook Controller"
    bl_idname = "Object Mode.mc_pie_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        # operator_enum will just spread all available options
        # for the type enum of the operator on the pie
        pie.prop(context.object.data, '["00_iSight Camera Indicator"]', text="iSight Camera Indicator Toggle")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PIE_template)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name = "Object Mode")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", "E", "PRESS").properties.name = "Object Mode.mc_pie_menu"


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PIE_template)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    #bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="VIEW3D_PIE_template")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are right clicking view source in the custom property in the UI.  Copy data_path will give you the path,  eg. `["prop"]` where the property name is prop.  In the material properties panel the rna_item will be the active material, in the object, the context.object, in the data `context.object.data`, in the `scene context.scene` etc.

The code you are seeing is setup to handle the different object types that can have a custom property.  `escape_identifier` most likely handles garbage property names.

The pie menu template.  A custom property "prop" has been added to the scene.  The 'rna_item' equates to `context.scene`, the key to "prop":

```
class VIEW3D_PIE_template(Menu):
    # label is displayed at the center of the pie menu.
    bl_label = "Select Mode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        pie.prop(context.scene, '["prop"]')
        # operator_enum will just spread all available options
        # for the type enum of the operator on the pie
        pie.operator_enum("mesh.select_mode", "type")
```

Comment: Thank you! I have the data path in now, but I'm still a bit confused with the context.something... For 3 of the properties I'm change a node value, and one of them is a bone rotation. What contexts would I use for those?

Comment: Ok, I found the context in the python tool tip for the custom property, but its not showing up in the pie menu...I've put my full code into the question.

Comment: Nevermind, got it, turns out it was just context.object!